# sending email using live id. after sending some mails i am getting error like Mailbox unavailable

Tags: c#, .net, email

i am sending email using live id. after sending some mails i am getting below error

Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.3.4 Requested action not taken; To continue sending messages, please sign in to your account.

if i sign to account i was asked to verify the account by entering some characters. but i dont want to do this every time.

please anyone can help me in this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this today. It is indeed a spam protection system, requiring you to enter a CAPTCHA on the website. You should be able to send if you manually log into your account, and complete the process (a bar appeared telling me I needed to do it above my inbox).

It said as an alternative, I could verify my account to bypass this in future. It provides a link to do so, and the process just involves giving them your mobile number.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is spam protection system. There is only one way to solve this - write program which would enter captcha for you.

Comment: after sending some more mails it is asking to validate the mail id by mobile

Comment: @Srinivas Sabbani: Now I'm absolutely sure that this is spam protection system. It prevents of usage of spam sending apps. And in this case you was detected as a spammer. Its not surprise that none of free mail servers did not allow to send unlimited mail. You are on a wrong way.

Comment: @Srinivas Sabbani: The fact that you are needing workaround, points that you are doing something illegal. So do it for you own risk. If you are not a spamer the only right way I can imagine, is to use you own mail server